# How to blend a quad, already with a texture on it

Tags: opengl, textures, alphablending

I made a quad with a nice texture on it. The texture has an alpha channel (RGBA). I replaced the quad with the texture `(GL_REPLACE)`, so now I have a billboard with (semi)transparant pixels on it.

So far, no problem.

But now I want to *blend the entire* billboard, so it's *overall opacity changes*.

**How would I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL_MODULATE, instead of GL_REPLACE, after setting the color to solid white, with an appropriate amount of alpha. (glColor(1,1,1,0.5) for instance)

(Should work fine on OpenGL. Seems likely it'll be good on ES, too.)

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work for some reason? I edited the question with our code.

Comment: If you just make a texture-less quad which is 1,1,1,0.5 does it appear translucent?